# python iterate select only string contains certain character

Tags: python, list, character

I want to iterate over kmers list and select items only contains character A , T, G and C

```
kmers=["AL","AT","GC","AA","AP"]

for kmer in kmers:       
    for letter in kmer:
        if letter not in ["A","T","G","C"]:
            pass
        else:
            DNA_kmers.append(kmer)
            print("DNA_kmers",DNA_kmers)
```

output:

```
DNA_kmers ['AL', 'AT', 'AT', 'GC', 'GC', 'AA', 'AA', 'AP']
```

desired output:

```
DNA_kmers=["AT","GC","AA"]
```

The only method i know is

```
if "B" in kmer or "D" in kmer or "E" in kmer or "F" in kmer or "H" in kmer or "I" in kmer or "J" in kmer or "K" in kmer or "L" in kmer or "M" in kmer or "N" in kmer or "O" in kmer or "P" in kmer or "Q" in kmer or "R" in kmer or "S" in kmer or "U" in kmer or "V" in kmer or "W" in kmer or "X" in kmer or "Y" in kmer or "Z" in kmer:
   pass
```

Comment: Are you guaranteed that the inner strings are always length 2 or that there is some sort of frequency pattern with the occurrences of characters? How important is efficiency--what size list and strings are you dealing with?

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks. I am newbies in python, working on practice file with file size around 400k bases. The kmer will be small list for practice.

Answer (score 2):

You code will currently add any items where either character is a match. We can adjust it to add only items where both characters match:

```py
kmers=["AL","AT","GC","AA","AP"]
DNA_kmers =[]

for kmer in kmers:       
    for letter in kmer:
        if letter not in ["A","T","G","C"]:
            break
    else:
        DNA_kmers.append(kmer)

print("DNA_kmers",DNA_kmers)
```

If you aren't familiar with Python, I've made use of the `else` clause on the `for` loop. This isn't available in all languages. The `else` block will be run if and only if the loop completes all iterations.

There are significantly simpler ways to do what you are trying to do. For example, the following will get the job done using a nested list comprehension:

```py
kmers=["AL","AT","GC","AA","AP"]

allowed = set("AGCT")
print([k for k in kmers if all([c in allowed for c in k])])
```

A more performant general-purpose solution is to use regular expressions:

```py
import re

kmers=["AL","AT","GC","AA","AP"]
r = re.compile("^[ATGC]*$")
print([k for k in kmers if r.match(k)])
```

If we limit the problem to only k-mers where k=2, we can further optimize the performance. The regex performance should increase slightly if matching a fixed length string, such as using `[AGCT]{2}`. We can also use `product` to create a set to use for constant time lookups:

```py
import itertools

kmers=["AL","AT","GC","AA","AP"]

allowed = {a+b for a,b in itertools.product("AGCT", repeat=2)}
print([k for k in kmers if k in allowed])
```

Comment: @ggorlen I'm not sure if it gets reallocated each time or not, but I've updated my answer to pull out the initialization. This appears to be about 2x faster: https://repl.it/@jncraton/ImmaterialPassionateIrc#main.py

Comment: Yeah but `all` still has no early bailout, so if `k` is 100000 length and the first character isn't in `allowed`, you really want to stop right away. See my answer for the correct version. The caveat, as I mentioned, is that if the string lengths are always 2, the allocation overhead of the generator might make it slower than the LC. I asked OP to clarify.

Comment: @ggorlen True. It looks like the `re` method is the fastest out of these solutions. The expression gets compiled down to something efficient that includes the early bailout you describe.

Comment: The reason the `re` version is fast on short strings is that it has the least object alloc overhead in the loop relative to LC and generator and that's the bottleneck.

Comment: `r.match` may fail on strings greater than length 2 - it is only looking at the first two characters of the string.  `bool(r.match('ATQ'))` ->> `True`. But we are speculating till OP clarifies.

Comment: `r1 = re.compile(r'^[^BDEFHIJKLMNOPQRSUVWXYZ]*$')` should suffice for any length string.

Comment: @wwii True. I've updated the re to handle strings of arbitrary length.

Comment: @ggorlen That appears to be correct. I added a version that uses a set lookup, and it is the fastest.